# How to reload checkout page if payment failed in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom payment gateway where I need to reload checkout page if payment failed.

#### Reason:

When Card details submitted the payment gateway generates a card token which I need to process the payment but we can use the card token only once with a request.

#### What I need:

Currently, I am just showing the error message and a return when payment is failed.

```
if($payment_status['status']){
    
    $order->update_status( 'on-hold', __( "ABC Payment Done\n", 'stackoverflow' ) );
    
    wc_reduce_stock_levels($order_id);

    WC()->cart->empty_cart();

    return array(
        'result'    => 'success',
        'redirect'  => $this->get_return_url( $order )
    );
  
}else{
    
    wc_add_notice( $payment_status['message'] , 'error' );
    return;
}
```

How can I reload/refresh the page if payment failed? S user can enter the card details again and we can process the payment.
Or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You need return the `array` for example:

```
if ( $payment_status['status'] ) {
    $order->update_status( 'on-hold', __( "ABC Payment Done\n", 'stackoverflow' ) );
    wc_reduce_stock_levels($order_id);
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    return array(
        'result'    => 'success',
        'redirect'  => $this->get_return_url( $order )
    );

} else {
    $order->update_status( 'failed', __( 'Payment error:', 'woocommerce' ) . $this->get_option( 'error_message' ) );
    wc_add_notice( $payment_status['message'] , 'error' );
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    return array(
        'result'   => 'failure',
        'redirect' => WC()->cart->get_checkout_url()
    );
}
```

That code will redirect to the `checkout` page. Hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want it sync or async.
Sync way:
header("Refresh:0");

It refreshes your current page. You can specify also the page you want:

header("Refresh:0; url=another_page.php");

Async way:
Generate the content dynamically, clean all changes and tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Fksjii is true.

However, it might be cleaner to have a specified page that generates token code.

With an XHR request you can get it, then submit every data with an XHR and wait for a callback.

However, if you can't edit JS code you might do

```php
if ($failed) {
   unset($_REQUEST);
   Header("Refresh: 0");
   exit;
}
```

Do not forget to clean $_GET or $_POST data before reloading your page.

It is always very important to exit even after a redirection sent in the headers. Indeed, headers are sent but code continue to execute and it could create some bugs.